# bootstrap validator show value in error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I having trouble showing the field value in the error message

Lets say i have an input field, if the user enters "something"

I would like the error message to say "something" is not available

At the moment i get this displayed

```
[object HTMLInputElement]is not a valid url
```

Here is the bit of jquery. So i tried to just display url but its not correct

```
url: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Enter a url!'
                    },
                    uri: {
                        message: url +'is not a valid url'
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: if possible then provide a fiddle.

Comment: try..  url.val() instead url

Comment: try this: `url.value`